# Why is php-json module mangling my utf-8 strings?

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8

Why does this:

```
<?
var_dump ( json_decode('{"unicode":"\u30d7\u30ec\u30b9\u30ad\u30c3\u30c8"}') );
?>
```

give me:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["unicode"]=>
  string(18) "ãã¬ã¹ã­ãã"
}
```

when according to the docs it should be "プレスキット"

This happens to me on one machine running PHP 5.1.6 with this module installed as per the instructions on http://www.aurore.net/projects/php-json/ and on a machine running PHP 5.2.11

Comment: Sounds like a problem with php-cli, not php-json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let the browser know to interpret the data as UTF-8 by sending an HTTP header prior to outputting the actual JSON like so:

> header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Note that headers must be sent before any other output. You should probably read up on the HTTP spec and learn about how headers are used. Here's [a link to get you started](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm) with sending HTTP headers in PHP.

---

**UPDATE**

In an instance like this where the correct headers have been sent, it's important to make sure the locale settings on your testing machine allow for UTF-8 characters. If the default locale on your system doesn't support UTF-8 and you don't have one installed that does, you'll never see the correct output. You can read [a little more about this here](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8)

Comment: The API in question does indeed return: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` but this also happens on the command line, entering strings manually instead of querying the API, as in the question.

Comment: Have you checked the UTF-8 data for ["well-formedness"](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets#checking_utf-8_for_well_formedness)? Also, if the default locale on your system doesn't support UTF-8 and you don't have one installed that does, you'll never see the correct output. Read [more about this](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) ...

Comment: Thanks, it was the locale thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to output a UTF-8 charset header, or your browser is free to interpret the raw json string however it wants, e.g. as ISO-8859 instead.

Comment: If I have a RESTful API that is just returning json encoded strings, how does one specify charset?

Comment: The API in question does indeed return:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

but this also happens on the command line, entering strings manually instead of querying the API.
We are talking about php itself, no browser is involved.